# Redirect url using clean url in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-shortener, clean-urls

i'm building a simple e-commerce app and i'd like to make my url's "clean".
Ok, i've already done some stuff to get there but i'm getting confused now :/

My current situation: 
www.example.com/products 
On this page i've some products with their id, title and all other stuff displayed 

When i click on the title of a product, i submit a form with the id & name and i'd like to goto 
www.example.com/detail/**name_of_product** 
`<form name="prodDetail" action="detail" method="post">`

In detail.php i get the product id by $_POST because it comes in by submitting the form. then i can do all my stuff as needed to display the product details. 
 So far so good.
but if i do `<form name="prodDetail" action="detail/'.$prodName.'"method="post">` i got nothing but a blanc page :/ Notice the '**/**' if i replace it with a '**?**' then it works but i got an ugly url with an ? in it:/

So i think my htaccess file doesn't alow me doing that :/

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&1id=$2&2id=3$ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$          index.php?action=$1&2id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$                  index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

i'm alo using a 'switcher.php' this file catches the 'action' and swith me to the right page using a function. i call this script in my index.php.

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "default";

switch ($action){
  case 'product';
    showproduct();
    break;
  default:
    defaultpage() //home.php is default
}
```

So if i submit a form to 'detail' the switcher points me to detail.php.

Sry for my bad english
Hopefully someone can help me :)

Comment: `1id` looks strange for me. Keys should not begin with a decimal. `id1` would make more sense.

Comment: yeah :/ I took it from an website so didn't change it.